# Vue.js: render root template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension and they don't support `template` function, so I have to pre-render templates using `render` function (I'm using webpack, vue-loader and vue-template-compiler).

I'm loading my root template like this:

```
import rootTemplate from './rootTemplate.vue';

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: createElement => createElement(rootTemplate),
  data: {...}
});
```

But when I'm doing it this way my root template becomes a child component, and it's children components become 3rd level components. But I want it to be root and it's children to be 2nd level.

If I place the root template right in my main js (or vue) file or index.html it's just not being rendered (it's getting replaced with `<!--function (a, b, c, d) { return createElement(vm, a, b, c, d, true); }-->`).